# Deleting an array of pointers vs deleting a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

When we call

```
delete[] array; // array is a pointer to an array
```

or

```
delete[] vector; // vector is a pointer to a vector
```

Assuming these are array/vector of linked list head pointers: Do these 2 statements call the destructors for every item in them? Or should we loop through them, delete each item and then delete[] the array or vector itself?

Let me be more specific,
If the array holds a head pointer with its destructor is called it deletes its next node or that it points to.

Comment: you do not delete a vector with `delete[]`

Answer (score 6):

Your second code snippet is incorrect. `delete` and `delete[]` are two different operators. `delete` is for delete an instance created by `new` and `delete[]` is for delete an array of elements created by `new[]`.

In C++, arrays and vectors does not care about what they store. For both array and vector, you need to delete each item (if they were allocated using `new`) before deleting the array and the vector.

If you create the array like this

```
Sample* arr[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    arr[i] = new Sample();
}
```

you need to delete them like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    delete arr[i];
}
```

If you create the vector like this

```
vector<Sample*> arr;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    arr.push_back(new Sample());
}
```

you need to delete like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    delete arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting an array of pointers delete[] array is suitable, but for an vector of pointers i would use a construct like this:

```
std::vector<Data*> m_data;
while(!m_data.empty()) delete m_data.back(), m_data.pop_back();
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `delete[]` on a `std::vector` is not correct C++. The vector is destroyed when it goes out of scope or when you `delete` a pointer to it if allocated on the heap with `new`. In both cases, however, destroying the array/vector does not call `delete` on the pointers it contains - you need to iterate through and do this yourself if you need to free that memory.