# Regarding deleting array of dynamic objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to delete the array of dynamic objects created in this following snippet?

I tried to go through some previous answers in the forum, but none could point answer for me.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Card{int x;};
int main()
{
    std::vector<Card*> S;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Card* o = new Card;
        o->x = i;
        S.push_back(o);
    }



    for (auto a : S)
        std::cout << "Opening from the container " << a->x << '\n';

//delete o; --------> How to delete the array of objects???
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting an array of pointers vs deleting a vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476159/deleting-an-array-of-pointers-vs-deleting-a-vector-of-pointers)

Answer (score 1):

By looping through the vector and calling `delete`:

```
for(auto& elem : S)
{
  delete elem;
}
```

Also, It's a good habit to range-loop over a container using `(const) auto&` instead of `auto` to prevent copies.

Also also, since you're using range-based for loops that means you have access to smart pointers so in reality you shouldn't be calling `delete` at all nor storing raw pointers.

Either store actual objects in the vector or store smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: When doing `delete elem` in the loop, it is not necessary to use a reference at all.  `delete elem` works based on the value of the pointer, and that doesn't change if the loop uses a reference.